# When a function having the Darboux Property represents a function of baire class one?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, pointwise-convergence

> $D(0) =\{f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}: f \text{ has the Darboux Property}\}$

> $D(1) =\{f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}: \exists (f_n)\subset D(0)\text{ and } f_n
>  \overset{\text{pointwise}}\to f\}$

---

> $B(0) =\{f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}: f \text{ is continuous}\}$

> $B(1) =\{f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}: \exists (f_n)\subset B(0)\text{ and } f_n
>  \overset{\text{pointwise}}\to f\}$

---

Then $B(0) \subset B(1) $ and $D(0) \subset D(1) $

Again $B(0) \subset D(0) \subset  D(1) $

**Question 1**: Is $B(1) $ and $ D(0)$ comparable under set inclusion $\subset$?

**Attempt**:

$f:[0, 1]\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(t)= \begin{cases}1& t\in (0,1]\\0& t=0\end{cases}$

Then $f\in B(1) $ but $f\notin D(0) $

---

$f\in D(0) $ i.e $f:[0, 1]\to\Bbb{R}$ has the Darboux property.

1. $f:[a, b]\to \Bbb{R}$ differentiable then $f'\in D(0) $ but $f'\in B(1) $ aslo i.e $\{f' :f\in D[a,b]\}\subset B(1) \cap D(0) $
2. Indicator function of $\Bbb{Q}$, the Cantor set are in $B(1) $ but none of the function have the Darboux property.
3. Finally I have found an example $($thanks to [J.H.Conway](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway)$)$ [Conway base 13 function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) which is in Baire class $2$ but have the Darboux property.

$\boxed{\text{Answer ( of Question $1$) : No.}}$

---

---

> **Question $2$** : Under what minimum assumption (weaker assumption) $D(0) \subset B(1) $ ?

**Points to be considered :**

• If $f\in D(0) $ and $f$ preserve compact sets then $f\in B(0) \subset B(1) $.

• If $f\in D(0) $ has a primitive then $f\in B(1) $

•$D_f$ is countable then $f\in B(1) $. Here $f$ is not an ordinary function,$f\in D(0) $.What kind of simplification it can bring in $D_f$ ?

---

Comment: Do you know about the 1965 Bruckner/Ceder survey paper on Darboux functions (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/93690/15780))? I don't have time now to think about your question, but this is the first place I'd recommend you to look. See also Ceder's 1984 survey paper *A survey of Darboux Baire* $1$ *functions*, especially [a google search of its title](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ceder+%22A+survey+of+Darboux+Baire+1+functions%22&filter=0).

Comment: I'm still extremely busy, but I happened to see this again and remembered something of possible interest I wrote in [this 21 May 2008 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/Pk_pWyP-8Pc/m/YcnSAIVzTbwJ): *Every derivative is both Baire one (a pointwise limit of continuous functions) and Darboux (has the intermediate value property). Each of these properties is nice in some ways, but when taken together they provide us with something that is
much nicer than we might expect, kind of like how “compact” and “Hausdorff” behave in general topology,* **(continued)**

Comment: *which when taken together form a class of spaces far better behaved than you'd guess based on how nice each of these individual properties is.*